# How to make .jar from .class

Tags: java

I have a working .class file but when I use

```
jar cvf MyJar.jar *.class
```

I the resulting MyJar.jar could not be opened:

> "The Java JAR file “MyJar.jar” could not be launched. Check the
>   CONsole for possible error messages."

Thanks for helping.

==========
EDIT:

```
> build
  > MyClass.class
  > MyClassCanvas.class
  > MyClassFrame.class
  > manifest.txt
```

manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: MyClass
```

Comment: How are you trying to 'open' the jar? Did you check the console for error messages?

Comment: Then it is wrong, because there isn't such class. At least I don't see any **AtomViewer.class** class there

Comment: @Lukino sorry I meant MyClass.class functions as desired.

Comment: If **MyClass.class** has main method (one that has signature **public static void main(String[] args)) then **Main-Class: MyClass** should be used.

Comment: Thanks. MyClass has main method, Main-Class: MyClass is used, but the .jar file can't be launched. Any other reasons why this might be happening?

Comment: Try running command that I added to my Answer.

Comment: Hi Lukino, I redid everything and it is working now. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: It was bugging me why, and it looks that you may not have empty line, is that right ? Could you try it ?

Comment: Yes. If the empty line is deleted, it would not work. However I am not sure if that's the reason. I did follow the instructions in your link and added a new line in the manifest.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you need to add manifest to your jar. Call it **manifest.txt** and must have at least following line:

```
Main-Class: YourClass
# remove comment, but leave empty line
```

YourClass is same name as your YourClass.class file without extension and that class must have main method (public static void main(String[] args).

If you have you main class in subdirectories, you must use them (they are considered as packages. For instance if you have directory **com/foo/YourClass.class**

```
Main-Class: com.foo.YourClass
# remove comment, but leave empty line
```

Then pack it with your JAR:

```
jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

For more see [Manifest](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)

EDIT:

I recommend to use at least maven. Make life easier if you have other dependencies or so. Then you add and configure maven-jar-plugin and that does a lot of stuff for you.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you don't need to use manifest file, but you can achieve all this with following command

```
jar cvfe MyJarName.jar MyClass *.class
```

where
    e - specify entry point - MyClass in your case

Comment: I have added a manifest.txt and I am getting stuff like: added manifest adding: MyClass.class(in = 1605) (out= 849)(deflated 47%) adding: MyClassCanvas.class(in = 610) (out= 369)(deflated 39%) adding: MyClassFrame$AlternateBasis.class(in = 2532) (out= 1463)(deflated 42%)..... The resulting .jar still can't be launched.

Comment: Did you use **tar** or **jar** ? See link at the end of my post and read that page.

Comment: Thanks. I used jar and followed the instruction you posted. Still can't make executable jar.

Comment: @Alicia: 
I did TYPO in 1 example, but it is OK in 2nd. It should be **Main-Class** not **Main-class**. If that not helped, please edit your question with dir structure you are building from. Which class have main method and content of manifest.txt you use, so I could reproduce it.

Comment: original post edited, the AtomViewer.class functions as desired.